# ScrollPane containing JTable takes up height of COntainer

Tags: java, swing, jtable, scrollpane

I have a `ScrollPane` and `JTable` that should only have one row of data.

```
String[] daysOfWeek = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
        String[][] data = {{"None","None","None","None","None","None","None"}};

        JTable mTable = new JTable(data, daysOfWeek);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(mTable);
        mTable.setFillsViewportHeight(false);
```

I want the `ScrollPane` to fit around the borders of the table but at the moment the height of the Scrollpane takes up the entirety of the container, making it look really ugly. I don't understand why, since I set `mTable.setFillsViewportHeight(false)`.

Any help how to achieve a `ScrollPane` that doesn't stretch beyond the size of the table would be welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());`

edit

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class ChangeNotifiersOnEvent extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private boolean runProcess = true;
    private Random random = new Random();
    private javax.swing.Timer timerRun;
    private Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    private String[] columnNames = {"Source", "Hit", "Last", "Ur_Diff"};
    private JTable table;
    private Object[][] data = {{"Swing Timer", 2.99, 5, 1.01},
        {"Swing Worker", 7.10, 5, 1.010}, {"TableModelListener", 25.05, 5, 1.01}};
    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

    public ChangeNotifiersOnEvent() {
        table = new JTable(model) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }
        };
        model.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {

            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent tme) {
                if (tme.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE) {
                    if (tme.getColumn() == 1 && tme.getLastRow() == 2) {
                        double dbl = ((Double) table.getModel().getValueAt(2, 1))
                                - ((Integer) table.getModel().getValueAt(2, 2));
                        table.getModel().setValueAt(dbl, 2, 3);
                    } else if (tme.getColumn() == 1 && tme.getLastRow() == 0) {
                        prepareUpdateTableCell();
                    } else if (tme.getColumn() == 1 && tme.getLastRow() == 1) {
                        executor.execute(new MyTask(MyTask.UPDATE_TABLE_COLUMN));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        table.setRowHeight(30);
        table.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(180);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    private void prepareUpdateTableCell() {
        timerRun = new javax.swing.Timer(10, UpdateTableCell());
        timerRun.setRepeats(false);
        timerRun.start();
    }

    private Action UpdateTableCell() {
        return new AbstractAction("Update Table Cell") {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                double dbl = ((Double) table.getModel().getValueAt(0, 1))
                        - ((Integer) table.getModel().getValueAt(0, 2));
                table.getModel().setValueAt(dbl, 0, 3);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (runProcess) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(330);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            changeTableValues();
        }
    }

    private void changeTableValues() {
        Runnable doRun = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                table.getModel().setValueAt(random.nextInt(128) + random.nextDouble(), 0, 1);
                table.getModel().setValueAt(random.nextInt(256) + random.nextDouble(), 1, 1);
                table.getModel().setValueAt(random.nextInt(512) + random.nextDouble(), 2, 1);

                table.getModel().setValueAt(random.nextInt(128), 0, 2);
                table.getModel().setValueAt(random.nextInt(128), 1, 2);
                table.getModel().setValueAt(random.nextInt(128), 2, 2);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doRun);
    }

    private class MyTask extends SwingWorker<Void, Integer> {

        private static final String UPDATE_TABLE_COLUMN = "update";
        private String namePr;
        private double dbl;

        MyTask(String str) {
            this.namePr = str;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            dbl = ((Double) table.getModel().getValueAt(1, 1))
                    - ((Integer) table.getModel().getValueAt(1, 2));
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    table.getModel().setValueAt(dbl, 1, 3);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ChangeNotifiersOnEvent frame = new ChangeNotifiersOnEvent();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocation(150, 150);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems to work. Why doesn't scrollPane.setPreferredSize(mTable.getSize()); work? This should set the scrollPane dimensions to my table dimensions, but if I add this line then the scrollpane and table disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you explicitly set a scroll pane's preferred size using `setPreferredSize(Dimension size)`, the scroll pane computes it based on the preferred size of its nine components (the viewport, and, if present, the two scroll bars, the row and column headers, and the four corners). The largest factor, and the one most programmers care about, is the size of the viewport used to display the client. see here for more: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html